# C# - How to reset a variable to its first state?

Tags: c#

I want to reset a variable to its first state without entering its first value again. I don't want to return the entire program to its first state with "Main()" or type "a = 5".

```
int a = 5;                                                     
a = 0;
```

*this is where I need to reset the variable without typing "a = 5" or returning program entirely to its first state with "Main()".*

I have tried Googling this but it didn't help so much.

Comment: you probably need another variable to remember it

Comment: @fubo there is no answer to my question?

Comment: There is no such thing as resetting a variable to original value. Once the value is changed, any values that were previously used are not remembered. You have to assign the original value to the variable again

Comment: @OlivierRogier if I use int aDefault = a; its value would also change with a

Comment: There is no built-in way to do that. You will have to write code.

Comment: @user13988674 No: `a` is not a pointer nor a reference. In [.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/) it is an [integral numeric](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types) - [value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types) just like in C, else .NET would have been too slow and problematic, too big a break with the habits of high-level languages such as C, C ++, Pascal, Java...

Comment: It would be useful if you mentioned why you want to do this? What is the actual purpose?

Comment: @OlivierRogier all wrong, buddy. Personal hobby project.

Comment: Push the value on a stack, pop to retrieve it. You can also of course make it difficult and introspect the C# IL to find the constant of the first assignment instruction, the address of the variable that was used, and then do a blind assembly copy. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to write your own class that remembers the "undo" history for assignments, and then assign values to the class using a method like Assign(), that not only sets the value but creates the undo history for it. Then, an Undo() method could pop off. You could even have a Redo() function. There is no assignment operator override in C# but you can probably have code so it automatically converts to the underlying type, which could be a template, so accessing the value would work normally.

Comment: OP asks to reset a value, not to have an undo buffer about which no sample code is provide to be able to implement it.

Comment: @OlivierRogier An "undo" function accomplishes what OP wants in a more generic way. "Undo" is a more standard feature than "Reset" and if OP wants to limit the history to one entry, that is easy to accomplish. The OP did not ask for help implementing a class to accomplish an "Undo" feature... the valuable contribution of this answer is to help OP think in those terms. If OP wants help writing something like that, OP can ask a new question, update this question or likely find existing questions that answer whatever questions OP has.